# Problems linking boost's filesystem in CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm using the filesystem library from Boost in this project (https://github.com/marcomedrano1999/files_in_directory.git) and it works fine when I link the boost root to the proyect (I'm using Visual Studio), but I need it to be cross-platform so I implement the following in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.18.3")

project("listdir") 

find_package(Boost 1.73.0 REQUIRED filesystem) 

include_directories("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}") 

link_directories("${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")

add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" "Main.cpp")

target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

but when I tried to configure it in CMake the following error displayed:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem) (found suitable version
  "1.73.0", minimum required is "1.73.0")

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2177(find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

I'd tried several ways for this (as shown in the documentation page) but any of them have worked. Can someone tell me if I made something wrong?

Comment: Enable `Boost_DEBUG` option and see, which exact files and directories are searched for `filesystem` library. Then compare them with files and directories which you actually have. BTW, `Boost_DEBUG` is described in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Boost library in a non-standard location, then you can specify the Boost Installation directory via **BOOST_ROOT**:

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=<path to the boost installation directory> <... the rest of cmake options ...>
```

Also make sure that the filesystem part of boost is really installed (filesystem is a compiled library in contrast to other header only libraries).